# How to get static final property from ClassName.class?

Tags: java, static, final

I have array of classes like this.

```
private static final Class<?>[] CLASSES = new Class[]{
    First.class,
    Second.class,
};
```

Each class have property

```
    public static final String PROPERTY = "property_name";
```

Need to make loop to compare `PROPERTY` with specific string like this:

```
for (Class<?> item : CLASSES) {
    string.equals(item.PROPERTY)
}
```

But I could't find a way to escape from ".class" to get `item.PROPERTY`.

How to get `PEOPERY` in a correct way in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean using reflection?

Comment: @talex using 'getField' gives me "Unhandled exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException". So I assume no. Maybe I'm missing somth?

Comment: AFAIR you need to use `getDeclaredField` for private fields.

Comment: @talex this also gives me the same error.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ thanks, I guess it is, but don't know how to use it in this case (see other comments). Any suggestions?

Comment: @white-imp IDK it works for me. You can iterate thru all fields and print them to make sure that field is actually there and spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
    for (Class<?> item : CLASSES) {
        Field f = item.getDeclaredField("PROPERTY");
        string.equals(f.get(item));
    }
```

Comment: The argument to `get` is ignored when the field is static.

Comment: Thanks, but using 'getField' or 'getDeclaredField' gives me "Unhandled exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException". What It could be?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? it shouldn't be. Make sure you provide correct field name.

Comment: @matt true, but you still need to provide an argument if using `get()`.

Comment: I think semantically it is better to use `null` because the argument should be an instance of the class. The argument you're passing is an instance of a different object: `Class`. It's ignored anyways, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean how to deal with the exception?

```
enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] { ClassA.class, ClassB.class, };

    for (Class<?> item : classes) {
        Field f = item.getDeclaredField("PROPERTY");
        System.out.println(f.get(item));
    }
}
enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] { ClassA.class, ClassB.class, };

    for (Class<?> item : classes) {
        try {
            Field f = item.getDeclaredField("PROPERTY");
            System.out.println(f.get(item));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```